# Escaping a WPF DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm very new to MVVM in particular.

I have the following piece of XAML code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lsbTriggers" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedProductPart.TriggerViewModels}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate >
                    <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding WatchedVariable}" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedProductPart.AllVariables}" >                            
                    </ComboBox>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

I'm trying to make a list that contains a combobox for each TriggerViewModel.

The combobox's selected item is determined by the TriggerViewModel's WatchedVariable property.

However, I want the ItemsSource of the combobox to be a list of variables provided by the SelectedProductPart object.
I seem to be unable to do this because the datacontext has "zoomed in", if you will, on TriggerViewModels, due to it being the list's ItemsSource.

I've tried creating a new DataContext inside the combobox, but this seems to create two disconnected DataContexts where changing the value of the combobox does not result in a change of TriggerViewModel's WatchedVariable.

Is there a way I can escape the current DataContext so I can get to the SelectedProductPart's AllVariables list?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a `Binding` with ***explicit*** way specifying its source (via `ElementName`, `Source` or `RelativeSource`). In this case we use `RelativeSource`. It helps walk up the visual tree and target the source based on its type (`AncestorType`):

```
<ListBox x:Name="lsbTriggers" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedProductPart.TriggerViewModels}">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <HierarchicalDataTemplate >
          <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding WatchedVariable}" 
               ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.SelectedProductPart.AllVariables,
                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}" >
          </ComboBox>
       </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Note the `Path` is prepended with `DataContext`.